Two node High Availability clusters
It's a common knowledge that HA involves redundant nodes, but for the quorum it needs odd number of nodes, to have a tie breaker in case of cluster partition. That means, quorum-based cluster has to have at least three voting nodes.
Not all of the voting nodes need to be able to run a full load: third one may be present merely for the tie breaking purpose. All the major server clustering technologies support such a setup, the tie-breaking node can be called witness (Hyper-V, VMWare vSphere), qdevice (corosync), arbitrator (in MariaDB Galera), whatever. That even can be a shared storage, which also acts as a third node by having some state using SCSI-3 persistent reservations. All right with that, since it's independent.
But "traditional" storage systems, network appliances and so on are often deployed with only two "nodes". For example, all SANs I've seen have two controllers (that is, HPE MSA, HP EVA, HP 3PAR, Dell Unity). Likewise, network appliances can work in a "highly available" manner with only two "nodes": consider two units of Cisco Catalyst 3570-X stacked, and Cisco Catalyst 6500 supports two supervisors. VMWare vSphere (not vCenter) cluster is said to be able to operate with two nodes without witness. Last but not least, HP C7000 blade enclosure has slots for two Onboard Administrators.
Why can we consider all of these systems highly available? Do they have different assumptions? Not a quorum-based? For instance, I suspect stacked switches would operate independently in case of stack partition, which already makes them not truly highly available because the connectivity of nodes would certainly suffer. And everything else has a "chassis" with some active components, and there can be a component that is designed to operate as a tie breaker for the "cluster". Or, chassis-enclosed system can potentially be built with an assumption that partition is physically impossible, and the loss of the partner is considered by the surviving node as that partner has failed, rebooted, physically removed, whatever, so it's certainly not a partition.
Am I right here?

The devices that are managed by those two controllers can in some cases be seen as the "third node", quorum disk  or tie breaker when the two controllers can't see each directly anymore. I think the managed devices should be able to report "I see you, controller 1"  and "I also see controller 2"  or some perturbation. And the managed device holds the only source of truth, there can't be a split brain caused by the unique data existing in only one of either controller.

I think of quorum as the capability to answer "did another node drop out" or did I drop out? If I cannot reach either other node or the quorum I'm not going to attempt a potentially destructive takeover of file shares. Network HA is a different animal with many different and interesting scenarios like DNS name resolution.

I mainly meant the network as a backend for a computer cluster communications. Like it's usually drawn, a stack, servers are connected to each member, and these links are teaming with LACP or some other way to look as a single L2 entity. If a stack is partitioned then, the behavior of teams on computers is undefined and there will be connectivity issues. Especially if L3 functions of switch are going to be used.

Network switches or routers hold no global state that would require quorum. (After all, packets sent to the same destination don't "overwrite" each other, so there's no need to reserve it like with storage or to strictly keep order between them.)
Two routers in a HA setup don't need to globally agree on a single routing table, for example; instead each router locally calculates best routes according to its own view of its own connectivity (i.e. even in a HA configuration they operate independently).
And since the state they do have directly represents their network connectivity, mismatching state is not only normal but literally part of their function – especially in the case of network partition, where the now-separate routers or switches will naturally have different views of the network and different 'best' paths to the same destination.
For example, Ethernet's "Spanning Tree Protocol" has no need to remain consistent during a partition – that would only be counterproductive. Instead each side immediately "forgets" about the other side and recalculates a new tree of what's left.  Similar applies to dynamic IP routing protocols like BGP or OSPF.
I believe the same applies to redundant SAN storage controllers: they are functionally "switches" or "routers" for the storage network protocols, and their job is only to deliver traffic to the actual storage using whichever path happens to be available.
As far as I know, traditional "switch stacking" is generally used for expansion and ease of management (i.e. configuring a stack as if it were one unit) – not as a HA feature. To have high availability, a node (server or router) itself would have two connections, one to each switch, and the switches would likewise have independent uplink connections in addition to being interconnected themselves (the interconnection could be a stack link but not necessarily). If their interconnection is broken, both switches recalculate their own views of the STP and continue operating.

Most SANs provide thinly provisioned volumes, snapshots, synchronization to another system, etc. All of this requires metadata to be stored and retrieved, and inherently cached in the controller, and problem with correctness and coherency arises. They have state. They aren't nearly as simple as "switches or routers".


It's a common knowledge that HA involves redundant nodes

Not necessarily.

but for the quorum it needs odd number of nodes

Only if the cluster requires a quorum
You go on in the question to discuss clusters which do not require a quorum.
The key issue here is, where there is more than one node capable of performing a particular task and the task can only be performed by one node, who choses which node to use? That could be the client (e.g. storage multipath, Multi-MX SMTP) or another service node deciding without seeking quorum consensus (e.g. CARP). Both present the possibility of split-brain behaviour, so (typically where persistent state change is the mix) are usually accompanied by some STONITH mechanism.
There are also common scenarios where tasks do not have to be performed by a single node - e.g. a static content HTTP server, or a DNS server.

Not necessarily. — can you elaborate on this? I was under impression that the only way to increase availability of the service which is provided by unreliable entities is to have redundant entities performing the serving, and coordinating them in a way that all of them are unlikely to fail simultaneously. Can you suggest another way?

"can you elaborate on this" - I thought I just had. I think you need to consider what "redundant" means in this context and the difference between active/passive and active/active AS WELL AS your fixation on quorum. "and coordinating ...unlikely to fail simultaneously" - Do you coordinate the failures of your cluster?

A quorum mechanism is for managing unavailability towards internal components, whereas high availability (HA) itself is just for managing unavailability towards external components. Many services by design do not care for strict consistency and thus do not need the added guarantees provided of a quorum.
This can be either because the service itself is robust to consistency failures (e.g. some management service in which the managed nodes can recover from inconsistency), is not reliant on consistency in the first place (e.g. because it uses a heuristic known to be not optimal) or because a split-brain failure is unlikely (e.g. each node is known to be much less reliable than its connection).
As a practical example, we have a High Throughput Computing (HTC) cluster in which "a central manager" component connects a few dozen-to-hundreds of queue nodes to a few hundred-to-thousands of worker nodes. The central component runs in a two-node high availability mode with simple state replication to the spare which takes over when the replication connection is gone too long. This setup actually has all the features mentioned above:

The central nodes are just arbiters between the queues and workers. Even if both were serving at once the queues won’t hand out tasks twice and the workers won’t overcommit. An erroneous HA state would be inefficient but not wrong.
The gist of HTC is that managers make the best guess at any moment but do not try to make accurate predictions or schedules. In an HA situation, be it failure or split-brain, each manager can operate on partial view and information because it never assumes a truly accurate view or information in the first place.
Each individual manager is by definition not redundant, and also highly complex and frequently tweaked - in contrast, our network is redundant, individually simple and rather static. That just makes it so much more likely that an unavailable manager is gone due to its own failure than a network/split-brain issue.


Two node high availability clusters behave better with special rules.
Only one node is required for quorum, not a majority. Without this, when the cluster partitions, neither node A or B have more than half, and will not take the resources. The service remains down after a failure.
However, to join the cluster and gain the authority to do anything, require all (two) nodes to communicate.  Without this, nodes can get stuck in a loop trying to fence the other one.
Stepping through a the events of a partition illustrates the fencing loop problem. Node A had the resources, but due to hardware faults lost both IP and shared storage communication. B fences A through out-of-band management, forcibly rebooting it. Up to now, this is what we want. But then A comes back and notices it is alone without resources, due to two node mode and not waiting, fences B in return. Even though B was in the process of taking over. Repeat.
For a practical implementation example, note that Corosync has a two_node option that implies wait_for_all.  As general purpose cluster software, stateful resources can be failed over if desired.  Such as file systems on top of shared storage, for a database.
Contrast to a cluster with more than two nodes. A majority is possible, enabling automatic and hopefully stable selection of a likely healthy node.  Even just one more node helps. After A loses communication and B takes over, C also agrees that B holds it. If B then fails, and A comes back, A and C get to decide who takes over.  No reboot loop, no need to wait for all nodes to join, because there is a majority decision.

Naturally, when building clusters, failure behavior should be tested. Distributed systems are tricky to begin with. And this involves forcibly taking over something from a computer that could have suffered arbitrary failures.
Subtleties and complexities of doing fail over clusters correctly do not make them popular. Unlikely users build two node from scratch. Pre-built appliances in a cluster configuration have done the design work in advance, and can limit the supported configurations.  Alternatives exist like not having a shared resource cluster, instead replicating another copy to an independent system, possibly distant in another geo.
